# How to restart the discord bot using commands [Python]

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

The title says it all, I have this bot I made, it's a game sort of, you enter the game via `@bot.command(name='join')` and it moves forward depending on inputs using:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message)
```

sometimes you just want to reset the game and you can't get out of the event, so what I want to know, is there a way to reset the bot using the commands ? tried to make it return but no luck, if not is there a way to make get out of the command used above.

Comment: Yes, but it probably requires a total redesign on your part.  Essentially, I would recommend pulling all of the game logic out into a separate class.  Each channel/server gets its own instance of the class, and your commands are just a delegation layer that determines which instance to call the methods of.  You can then restart the game by replacing the running instance with a fresh instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm a bit new to all this so not sure I can express it in an accurate manner but, I have make everything into functions outside the bot.command, and they start calling each other till some conditions are met after I use the command (let's say !join), the problem is once you call this command, the game starts and you can't stop it, I can't for instance call it again.

Answer (score 1):

Use await.bot.logout [DOCS LINK](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.login)
and await.bot.login [DOCS LINK](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.logout)
I think.

Use arguments in the login one:

`await login(token, *, bot=True)`

Hope this helps!

Edit: this will completely log off and then log on the bot.